# authorize myself to mailchimp api

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers

guys, I am trying to authorize myself to Mailchimp API but its give me 401 error can any find a problem in the code I am using request

```
  app.post('/',function(req,res){
    var firstname=req.body.first;
    var lastname= req.body.last;
    var email= req.body.email;
    
    var options={
        url:'https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/47303a99f3',
        method: 'POST',
        header:{
             'Authorization':'Basic 55adfb745d93168c37966fbd734e46d1-us10'
        }
        

    };
 request(options,function(e,r,b){
    if(e){
        console.log(e);
    }else if(r){
        console.log(r.statusCode);
    }

 });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your `options` object.

The `request` module expects the `headers` attribute in options instead of `header` attribute. Hence your authorization header is not getting identified on the server side.

It should work if you update your options to:

```
var options={
        url:'https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/47303a99f3',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
             'Authorization':'Basic 55adfb745d93168c37966fbd734e46d1-us10'
        }
    };
```

[Reference.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers)